# How to parse a table row as parameter to a JS function onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, parameters

I have started to learn html and JavaScript and i can not find a solution for the following issue. 
I have following html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
        <hr/>
        <table border="1">

            <tr id="e1">
              <td><form id="form2"><input type="hidden" name="id"  />1</form></td>
                  <td><input form="form2" type="hidden" name="name"/>aaa</td>
                  <td><input form="form2" type="hidden" name="description" />xyz</td>
                  <td><input form="form2" type="submit"  onclick="doSmth(this.parent)" value="Details" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

By pressing the submit button I would like to parse all data elements from the table row("1","aaa","xyz) as parameters to my JavaScript function to proceed them. How can I do this the best way?I tried to give (this) as parameter or (this.parent) but it doesn`t seem to do what I intend at all.

All in all I want to achieve a table with a submit button in each row which submits a particular row.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's not a good idea to have a form control with a name of "name". Control names are added as properties of the form and reference the control, so `document.forms.form2.name` will reference the control, not the form's *name* property (similarly for properties like *submit* and *reset*). So use names that are unlikely to clash, e.g. "personId", "personName" and so on. ;-)

Comment: I will avoid this in the future. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the *form* property of controls doesn't work in all browsers (e.g. IE), so better to put the form around the entire table.

You can access all of a form's controls using its *elements* collection, then set the value of each control based on logic.

The following attaches a submit listener to the form, loops over all the controls and for each hidden control, sets its value to the *textContent* of its parent.

```js
function doSmth(event) {

  // Stop form submitting for now
  event.preventDefault();

  // Within the listener, *this* is the element that called the listener, i.e. the form
  // The form's elements collection gets all the controls in the form
  var controls = this.elements;

  // For each control that is an input, copy the adjacent text to the value
  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var control = controls[i];

    if (control.type == 'hidden') {
      control.value = control.parentNode.textContent;
    }
  }

  // Show values of controls
  [].forEach.call(controls,function(control) {
    console.log((control.name || control.type) + ': ' + control.value)
  }); 
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.forms.form2.addEventListener('submit', doSmth, false);
};
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
        <hr/>
        <form id="form2">
        <table border="1">
            <tr id="e1">
              <td><input type="hidden" name="id">1</td>
              <td><input form="form2" type="hidden" name="name">aaa</td>
              <td><input form="form2" type="hidden" name="description">xyz</td>
              <td><input form="form2" type="submit" value="Details"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work because it will process and submit the entire form, not the row in question.

Comment: @James—per the OP: "*I would like to parse all data elements from the table row("1","aaa","xyz)*". There is only one row, and all inputs in the OP are associated with the form by their *form* attribute (though IE doesn't understand that). If the OP had a multi-row table and only wanted to process one row of many, that is a different question but not difficult to accommodate.

Comment: That's not what I gather from "All in all I want to achieve a table with a submit button in each row which submits a particular row."

Answer (score 1):

you can assign id to each input element and then call them in the script:

```
      <table border="1">

        <tr id="e1">
          <td><form id="form2"><input type="hidden" name="id"  />1</form></td>
              <td><input form="form2" id="id1" type="hidden" name="name"/>aaa</td>
              <td><input form="form2" id="id2" type="hidden" name="description" />xyz</td>
              <td><input form="form2" type="submit"  onclick="doSmth()" value="Details" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <script>
    var myVar1 = getElementById('id1').val();
    var myVar2 = getElementById('id2').val();
    function doSmth (myVar1, myVar2){
        //do something
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I considered to give id to each element in my table too. But in my opinion it is not scalable enough because i will need thousands of variables to access each element by id.

Comment: Each control already has a name and can be accessed as a named property of the form, no need to add IDs. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This function looks for all "hidden" elements on your form, grabs whatever text comes immediately after the element, and sticks it into the value field of that element.  (If you want the form to actually submit as well, remove the e.preventDefault() line)

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=submit]');
for (var i=0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inps = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]");
    for (var i=0; i < inps.length; i++) {
      inps[i].value = inps[i].nextSibling.nodeValue;
    }

    // the rest of the function is just to display the contents of the form
    var f = document.getElementById('e1');
    var o = {};
    for (var i=0, el; el = f.elements[i]; i++) {
      if (el.type == 'hidden' && el.value) {
        o[el.name] = el.value;
      }
    }
    console.log(o);
  });
};
```

```html
<form id='e1'>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="id"  />1</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="name"/>aaa</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="description" />xyz</td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Details" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="id"  />2</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="name"/>bbb</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="description" />wgh</td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Details" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I am sorry I obviously didn`t express my problem correctly. If I understand this right i have to write new function for each new row with your solution. But I actually want one only function which handles each row of the table. I edited my post at the end. My goal is: "All in all I want to achieve a table with a submit button in each row which submits a particular row."

Comment: I made some changes to put the form in a valid location and having one submit button per row which operates on its row.  The main idea remains the same.